# Motor selection

Tags: mechanical-engineering, power

I am trying to build a linear actuator for which I am trying to select a appropriate motor. I need to move about 1 kg of weight at about 1.2 m/s using a stepper motor.

What specifications of the motor should I be looking at?

I know power, RPM and torque all play a big role, but not quite sure how to determine the motor based on the combination of those three.

From what I understand, torque happens when force is applied at an angle. RPM is just rotations per minute. The pulley's diameter will also change things. Wouldn't the belt rotate faster if I increase the diameter of the pulley since it covers more area of the pulley or is it the other way around?

In a bicycle for instance, the chain seems to move faster on a smaller gear which have large diameter but it goes slower. How will this affect the rpm and torque?

Answer (score 2):

First you need set your self tolerances, how critical is speed? If you want exactly 1.2m/s with +-0.5m/s? Also you will have to define a safety factor, so you generally want to increase the motor specs by 50% always better to have extra power to play with. Gears work in ratios, Bigger the gear in diameter with appropriate number of teeth will give you more torque smaller the gear higher rpm lower torque simple relation.

Comment: Thanks Arsalan! Ok....so +-0.5m/s is totally ok. This motor Bi Polar stepper motor https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13656 has a "Recommended Holding Torque: 125 oz.in"[not sure what that means actually. does it mean it has a torque of 125 oz.in?] under its specifications. How can I determine if this motor will be able to rotate the belt at the speed I want with the load on it? It doesn't say anything about rpm. What diameter of the pulley should I use? Thanks again.

Comment: A holding torque means it can stop at pole and hold a weight, But this is depended on the current drawed from PSU.. you can look at it as a electronic break. So it can hold 125oz at roughly 2A, Well how well this goes well in your application is depended on various factors, for example how heavy the gear is which is attached to the shaft of stepper motor, if you are planning to get more torque from your motor you can use a bigger gear and then use a slightly smaller gear to increase the rpm of the torque, Belt slippage happens when your RPM are to high or there is slack on the belt.

Comment: If you can upload a simple drawing of your applications with dimensions I might be able to give you a rough idea. Are you planning to do a rack and pinion setup?

Comment: This feels more like a comment than an answer in its current state.

Comment: Hi Arsalan - I am not sure how heavy it needs to be, but it can be as heavy as needed to get this to work. Preferred diameter is about 5 inches or less of the biggest gear. If its 5 inches, the gear will have to rotate 8 times a  second to cover 1 meter if its the only gear right? Hopefully I'm thinking about this correctly.  I will try to upload a diagram. I did think about a setup like rack and pinion, but for my specific need, that wont quite work. Please let me know what you think. Thanks!

Comment: First of all I think we need a simple drawing or schematic to access you needs secondly you can't correlate mass of gear with its size since that is dependant on the material used, a higher mass means more stability since the second moment of area or inertia is higher,

Answer (score 1):

I feel like I say this a lot, but it seems to be a commonly overlooked design spec.

Torque is a force applied (orthogonally) at some distance, but torque is *also* moment of inertia times angular acceleration.

What is your arrangement? You have a mass and a speed spec, but how long should it take to *accelerate* to that speed?

If you are trying to move a mass orthogonal to the gravity vector, then theoretically (no friction), it doesn't take any power to move it at any speed because power is work per time, and work is force times distance, and *there is no force* (other than friction/air resistance) *required to hold an object at a constant speed!*

In real life friction and wind resistance matter, but those are probably negligible at your desired speed.

So again, to spec your motor, you need to:

1. Determine *how quickly* you want to get to your rated speed, then
2. Choose a mechanism to convert rotary to linear motion, then
3. Find the moment of inertia *of the entire system* at the motor shaft, then
4. Multiply the moment of inertia by your desired acceleration to get your "rated torque", then
5. Multiply your linear speed by your gearing/belting/reduction ratio to get your "rated rpm", then
6. Multiply your torque by your rpm (in rad/s) to get your rated *motor (output) power*.

I would look for a motor at least 10% higher power than whatever you calculate because of efficiency loss in your rotary-linear conversion.

You can play around with gearing, but keep in mind you need to update moment of inertia (torque) and rpm when you do. Eventually you should reach a design that an off-the-shelf motor meets or exceeds.

If you have questions about how to calculate a moment of inertia, that's a good question and you should ask it. As it stands, I hope this explains how to go about choosing motor torque, rpm, and power.